# Configuration jetty server logging

Tags: spring, jetty, embedded-jetty

We would like to make jetty use log4j configuration for logging. I am using embedded jetty within spring based on this tutorial. I am followed this documentation to include all required slf4j and log4j dependencies in classpath.

Basically I added jetty-logging.properties to classpath with following configuration.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4Log
org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO
```

I also have log4j.properties in classpath

I have following maven dependencies to include required jars.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.9.v20130131</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I start up the jetty server via spring, the log output is always logged to StdErr and it's not logging to log file I configured in log4j.properties. Am  I missing anything? Is there any debugging I can turn on to troubleshoot ..? How can I get this to work?

Comment: Are you trying to configure Jetty's internal logging? Or use SLF4J for logging from your application?

Comment: Also, the tutorial you refer to doesn't seem to be linked.

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer to this question did help me find the answer, it took me a little bit more digging.

I was using Spring MVC with log4j.  The following

```
public class LaunchServer {

   private static final int SERVER_PORT = 8008;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      //Make sure you set the log before you start the server
      Log.setLog(new Slf4jLog());

      Server server = new Server();

      ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
      connector.setPort(SERVER_PORT);
      server.addConnector(connector);

      WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext();
      wac.setWar("war");
      wac.setContextPath("/");
      wac.setMaxFormContentSize(5242880);
      wac.setMaxFormKeys(100000);
      wac.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
      server.setHandler(wac);
      server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
      server.start();
   }
}
```

In my log4j2.xml file under the `<Loggers>` I put

```
<Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="debug" />
```

It worked well for me and avoided everything being logged to StdErr

Answer (score 0):

I got this answered via jetty [mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg03974.html).